# Why do methods on a function seem to not work on vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button

I have created a method that is triggered with a button `on:click` event, but it doesn't seem to work.

There is the code:

```
<template>
  <div class=button>
        <button v-on:click="refreshTemperature"  type="button"  > Search </button>
        <p> Temperature : {{ temp }} </p>
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  name: 'Meteo',
  data() {
    return {
      temp: Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 10) ) + 10,
  },
  methods: {
      refreshTemperature : () => {
           this.temp ++;

        }
}
```

When I click the button nothing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing a }. There should be one to end the `methods` object

Comment: forgot it when i copyed the code but on my source there is the brackets ;) that's not the problem unfortunately @AlexH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the arrow function, but the regular function.
You can refer to this [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods).

```
<template>
  <div class=button>
        <button @click="refreshTemperature"  type="button"  > Search </button>
        <p> Temperature : {{ temp }} </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Meteo',
  data() { 
    return {
      temp: Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 10) ) + 10,
    }
  },
  methods: {
      refreshTemperature() {
           this.temp ++;
          
        }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is a good practice, but doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Yeah that doesnt solve the problem

Comment: I updated my code. please remove arrow function.

Comment: You beat me! I just found that was the problem

Comment: Oh ok so arrow function doesnt works on methods: ? i dont get why this declaration doesnt works if u can explain me @WilliamWang

Comment: That's because an arrow function wouldn't bind `this` to the vue instance.
You can check here more details. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

Comment: @WilliamWang great answer! I suggest adding the documentation link into the original answer for better visibility and context to future readers